# How do I turn off a map click event

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I'm able to get map click events and want to turn off the click event handler once the event is received and handled.

I want to remove the event handler so that subsequent clicks on the map no longer cause the event handler to be invoked.

```
view.on("click", function(event) {
    var point = "point: (" + event.mapPoint.latitude + ", " + event.mapPoint.longitude + ")";
  console.log("click event: ", point);
  findStores(event.mapPoint.latitude, event.mapPoint.longitude);
  // now I want to disable the click event until it is re-enabled
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with [`arcgis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) I assume the `view` in your code example is an instance of `esri/views/View`.

Then, simply following the [documentation for `view.on()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-View.html#on), you just need to store and call the remove handler:

```
var handler = view.on("click", function(event) {
    var point = "point: (" + event.mapPoint.latitude + ", " + event.mapPoint.longitude + ")";
    console.log("click event: ", point);
    findStores(event.mapPoint.latitude, event.mapPoint.longitude);

    handler.remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out in the documentation. None of the examples / samples that I looked at removed the handler.